# How do I make the breadcrumb layout horizontal as opposed to its default vertical layout??

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, branding, breadcrumb

I am looking to style the breadcrumb to match my custom branding solution. Looking at styling the font-color,size,style etc and the image that separates them as well.

I would like to start by laying it out horizontally as opposed to vertical for starters.

How do I go about this?

Please do share links to any articles or sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need something like [Mavention simple SiteMapPath](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/create-sharepoint-breadcrumbs-mavention-simple-sitemappath/) I wrote my own custom for the site.

The crux is, you can't modify the 2010 breadcrumbs with css or transformation, to be how we see classic breadcrumbs being.